# Error when applying gradients with get_weights()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to apply custom gradients to my model.

Below, `actor_t` is my model. `get_weights()` returns a list of np.arrays and looking around in tensorflow's documentation and code, `apply_gradients` needs it to be a list of tensors.

```
def update_from_gradients(self, actor_gradients):
        grads_and_vars = list(zip(actor_gradients, self.actor_t.get_weights()))
        train_op = self.actor_opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)  # error here
```

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'

I also tried this:

```
weights = [tf.compat.v2.convert_to_tensor(w) for w in self.actor_t.get_weights()]
grads_and_vars = list(zip(actor_gradients, weights))
train_op = self.actor_opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

which raises the same error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_weights` will give you the current values of the weights in the model, as NumPy arrays. What you need are the trainable variables of the model, which you can get with the property `trainable_weights` or its alias `trainable_variables`.

```
def update_from_gradients(self, actor_gradients):
        grads_and_vars = list(zip(actor_gradients, self.actor_t.trainable_weights))
        train_op = self.actor_opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

Comment: Thanks. I also tried wrapping them with tf.Variable(w) for w in .get_weights(). Is that also correct (save for the redunant pass over the weights)?

Comment: @MakisKans Right, I don't know if that fails or not, but even if it doesn't it would not work... It would be creating new variables, so the optimizer would update those instead of the ones that are actually used by your model, so in practice it would have no effect.

Comment: Bugwise it does work. But what you said makes sense. Thanks for letting me know in advance and saving me time